# grails .gsp - how do I embed object properties when saving with a parent object

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a report page where the user is able to enter a number of totals. Each of these totals is a domain object in it's own right and has a number of properties of it's own that need to be persisted. For each of the totals, the user can only enter data into one field, which is just a number, yet the other properties of the total object are determined by where the particular total is output in the page.

I'd like to be able to save the whole report, and each on of those totals from just the one page.

What I can't work out is how do I add the extra params to each of the domain objects at the gsp end.

Say I have the following where `${reportInstance}` is the report that I'm currently working with but `${reportInstance?.totalHours?` refers to one of many `totalHours` objects I need to save from this page.

```
<input type="number" size="6" min="0" class="count-${location}" name="count-${location}" value="${reportInstance?.totalHours?.total}">
```

This input field gives me it's 'total' but I also need to save other properties for it such as `${location}` as well as others...

How do I add the extra properties to the single form value so that the controller can pick it up?

EDIT:

Am I able to nest properties in the value by doing something like:

```
<input type="number" size="6" min="0" class="count-${location}" name="count-${location}" value="${reportInstance?.totalHours?.total(location:location)}">
```

??

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're looking for is:

```
<g:hiddenField name="myField" value="myValue" />
```